# Где инициализируется контекст приложения в mvc?

Tags: java, spring

Где инициализируется контекст приложения в mvc?

Comment: Контекст инициализируется спрингом во всех приложениях по одному и тому же принципу. MVC это или нет - разницы нет.

Comment: вам это исключительно ради познания и интереса или же за этим у Вас стоят какие-то практические задачи, которые по Вашему могут быть решены как только Вы узнаете как инициализируется контекст в Спринг?

Comment: Вопрос интересный конечно, но большой и длинный. Поэтому я и спрашивал у Вас про практическое применение. В общем же виде статью по инициализации контекста можно день или два писать.

Comment: Вопрос, что бы осознать до конца как это все происходит, очень много информации по этому вопросу прочитал, уже каша получилась. Думал найдется опытный практик, который досконально может все разложить по полочкам, обновив свои знания и оказав посильную помощь подрастающему поколению)))